# npmのアップデート時に出る以下の警告文の意味と対処法について知りたい

Tags: npm

## 問題

`sudo npm update -g`といつもの通りアップデートしたところ、以下のような警告文が出ました。
意味と対処法を知りたいです。

```
 $ sudo npm update -g
npm WARN deprecated querystring@0.2.0: The querystring API is considered Legacy. new code should use the URLSearchParams API instead.
npm WARN deprecated mkdirp@0.5.1: Legacy versions of mkdirp are no longer supported. Please update to mkdirp 1.x. (Note that the API surface has changed to use Promises in 1.x.)
```

## 考えたこと

「`querystring@0.2.0`が非推奨」、「`mkdirp@0.5.1`が非推奨」というのは読み取れるのですが、どちらもnpmでインストールしていませんし、アップデートのしようがありません。
対策方法をお願いします。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

どちらも要約すると、あなたがインストールしたｎｐｍパッケージの内部には、仕様が古いパッケージがまだ使われている、という警告です。
警告を出しているパッケージの作者に要望してください。

Comment: 古いパッケージは、ユーザーではなく製作者がアップデートすべきもので、それを製作者に要望する、ということですか？

Comment: @ninniq  場合によります。今は、あなたがインストールしたパッケージのどれか（X とします）が、非推奨の `querystring@0.2.0` に依存している状態です。もし X に新しいバージョンが出ていてこの問題が解消されていたら、あなたが X をそのバージョンにアップデートすれば直ります。 X の最新版でもその問題が解消していなければ、 X の作者に修正を要望することになります。

Answer (score 0):

`npm ls querystring`（同様に`npm ls mkdirp`）を使えば、NPMモジュール（とその内部モジュール）間の依存関係というか、呼び出し経路を、簡易的なツリー状で表示してくれます。
※「このソースファイルの、だいたい何行目に使われてる」迄教えてくれたら、対処してくれやすそうな気がするのですが。